# Why is Elixir warning me that my import is unused?

Tags: import, compiler-warnings, elixir

I'm new to Elixir and encountered this. It does not make any sense to me, so I'm probably missing something.

Why is Elixir giving me this warning:

> lib/test.ex:3: warning: unused import

on that code

```
defmodule Test do
  def run(str) do
    import Poison
    obj = Poison.Parser.parse!(str)
    obj = %{obj | "name" => "bert"}
    obj = %{obj | "alter" =>  "30"}
    Poison.encode!(obj)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`import` is used to explicitely say you are going to use the imported module functions, without prefixing it with the module name.

http://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/alias-require-and-import.html#import

Thus, since you use these functions with the `Poison` prefix, the `import` remains unused, and you get the compiler warning.

Comment: Simply put, you can change `import` to `require` and the warning will go away.

Answer (score 2):

To amplify on Kernael's answer, modify your code this way:

```
defmodule Test do
  import Poison
  def run(str) do
    obj = Parser.parse!(str)
    obj = %{obj | "name" => "bert"}
    obj = %{obj | "alter" =>  "30"}
    encode!(obj)
  end
end
```

And the warning will go away. *(NB: I moved the import because that's slightly more idiomatic but it's fine where you've got it in your code too).*